# Apache Kafka Producer Consumer API Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to create a simple Java API to test Kafka Producer and Consumer. When I am running the producer and consumer on separate terminals on my Mac machine its working fine. But when I tried to connect to Kafka server using java api code, getting this error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafkatest2.ProducerTest.main(ProducerTest.java:34)

**Producer Code :**

```
    package kafkatest2;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
public class ProducerTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
   props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, String> producer = null;
    try {
          producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String msg = "Message " + i;
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("tested", msg));
        System.out.println("Sent:" + msg);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
    System.out.println("last");
      producer.close();
    }

  }

}
```

**Consumer Code :**

```
 package kafkatest2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class ConsumerTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1:2181");
    props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer1 = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    kafkaConsumer1.subscribe(Arrays.asList("tested"));
    while (true) {
      ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer1.poll(10);
      for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        System.out.println("Partition: " + record.partition() + " Offset: " + record.offset() + " Value: " + record.value() + " ThreadID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Please let me know what am I missing?? is there some issue with the configuration values??

Thanks,
Vipul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace indicates an NPE in your producer code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
kafkatest2.ProducerTest.main(ProducerTest.java:34)
```

This can happen if `producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);` throws an Exception. If so, when you enter the finally block, the local variable `producer` won't be defined so calling `producer.close()` will throw an NPE. Simply wrap the call to close in an `if (producer != null)` block.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your comments. But the issue is why  producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props); is throwing error.??? I am not able to resolve that.

Comment: The Producer code you pasted above works for me (tested with Kafka 0.11.0.1). If you still have issues, I suggest you enable log4j logging

For the Consumer, you need to remove `zookeeper.connect` and replace it with `bootstrap.servers` like you have in the Producer.

Comment: Can you please let me know where can I find the kaka-spark-streaming dependencies for 0.11 Kafka assembly?? I am trying to create a spark consumer, but getting errors due to missing classes.

Comment: import org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverLauncher;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Scheduler;
I am not able to get dependency for these two classes.

Comment: I don't know, I suggest you post a new question